# Prestashop function are disable

Tags: function, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

All function on Prestashop are disable.

I made a website in Prestashop back in 2015 and it was working fine for some years. Then it stop working and all the fuctions got disable.

The error it giving me is

`This funktion is disable`

Comment: which prestashop version do you used?

Comment: PrestaShop 1.6.1.1

Comment: You can contact with your hosting server author. they can update the server system.

Comment: why? how can they update it? they dont have acces to my prestashop. I cant even install a module. Everything is deactivated. How come?

Comment: They probably changed some php setting or disable a php module. Create a subfolder and try to install prestashop there. It should warn you of any missing module/setting. You don't even have to finish the install.